# UIView is not taking touch

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitouch

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    checkingOption = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 250, 17, 15)];
checkingOption.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
checkingOption.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
checkingOption.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    checkingOption.opaque = NO;
[self.view addSubview:checkingOption];
[checkingOption setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

That is my new on main view.now i want to test that is user touching on that or not...

```
-(void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

[self.usernameField resignFirstResponder];
[self.passwordField resignFirstResponder];
UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject]; 
CGPoint startPoint =[touch locationInView:checkingOption];
if(CGRectContainsPoint(checkingOption.frame,startPoint)){

    NSLog(@"touch inside the checking view");

}
```

Please help me..i am not finding the problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add UITapGestureRecognizer to your view

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapOne = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTapOne.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; singleTapOne.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; singleTapOne.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTapOne]; [singleTapOne release];
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
}
```

Comment: Actually i do get your point..how could i check my new view???...please if it is a stupidious question then never mind.i did not work on `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Thanks no need to help more i have solved it...Actually i only needed to set `UITouch *touch =[[event allTouches] anyObject]; 
 CGPoint startPoint =[touch locationInView:checkingOption];
 if(CGRectContainsPoint(checkingOption.bounds,startPoint)){
  NSLog(@"touch inside the checking view");
 }`